# Why Does the faucetts in my house sputter a bit ( like air in the lines, at times) when I turn them on, Hot, & Cold?

Tags: plumbing

I have my own well, & sometimes when I open any faucett, Hot, or Cold, I hear a little hissing sound, for a second or two then it works OK

Answer (score 1):

I believe that water underground, esp. in deep well can be highly pressurized.  That increases the amount of gasses that can be dissolved.  Bringing the water to the surface reduces that pressure and the dissolved gasses form real gasses (mostly oxygen and nitrogen) again.  That leads to an occasional "spurting".  I've never figured out why it's so random, but I've experienced the same thing on the water from my well.   I'm not sure of all of this, but that's what I think happens.

Comment: I agree this could be one cause another is the pump picking up air I have seen this with both submersible and jets.  For different reasons including cracks on the main line in the well water draining back (check valve keeping pressure in the tank) then pushing air into the pressure tank.